# retrieving RDS license

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I have a question, iam running a PowerShell command to retrieved RDS LicenseKeyPack details, according to [win32-tslicensekeypack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/win32-tslicensekeypack) KeyPackType should a number between 0 and 6, yet i am getting 7 on some outputs. What dose this mean?.

Example output:

```
KeyPackId         : 3
KeyPackType       : 2
ProductVersion    : Windows Server 2016
TypeAndModel      : RDS Per User CAL
AvailableLicenses : 48
IssuedLicenses    : 1202
ExpirationDate    : 20380101000000.000000-000

KeyPackId         : 5
KeyPackType       : 7
ProductVersion    : Windows Server 2012
TypeAndModel      : RDS Per User CAL
AvailableLicenses : 0
IssuedLicenses    : 1
ExpirationDate    : 20380119031407.000000-000

KeyPackId         : 7
KeyPackType       : 7
ProductVersion    : Windows Server 2016
TypeAndModel      : RDS Per User CAL
AvailableLicenses : 0
IssuedLicenses    : 49
ExpirationDate    : 20380119031407.000000-000"
```